# Change editext cursor color in API 12

Tags: android, customization, android-edittext

I was trying to customize Android `edittext` cursor. I found many solution using `android:textCursorDrawable=""`on Google and StackOverflow. But it is available from API 12.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Android"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/my_cursor_drawable" />
```

I want to do that from API 8. So is it possible to change `edittext` cursor color in < API 12 ?

Comment: Did you have any luck on this one yet??

Answer (score 1):

You could try this(with java reflection),

```
try {
    Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(et1, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
} catch (Exception ignored) {}
```

reference :[How to Change programatically Edittext Cursor Color in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996032/how-to-change-programatically-edittext-cursor-color-in-android)