# searchview cursor color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have an app with light theme but dark actionbar. So my colorControlActivated is my primary color (green) and with the light background, the edittext cursors are green. The problem is that my actionbar is green so when using the search text in the actionbar I don't see the cursor because it's the same color. How can I change the cursors color to white just in the actionbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchView` is a complex view, which consists from multiple views, including `EditText`. So you can get `AutoCompleteTextView` from it, using `findViewById()` or reflection. If you use support lib, you can use next code.

```
searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

Then just set cursor to `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: and how do i set cursor?

Comment: @Yamila `AutoCompleteTextView` is `EditText` so you can use any method, that is described for EditText, for example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26543290/3858030