# Change color edittext selection handles programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the color of an edittext programmatically. It works but as you can see from the image attached, the icons for the text selection are still using the theme color accent instead of the blue I set. How can I change it? My current code is:

```
editText.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]{StateSet.WILD_CARD}, new int[]{color}));
setCursorDrawableColor(editText, color);

private void setCursorDrawableColor(EditText editText, int color) {
    try {
        Field fCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        fCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
        int mCursorDrawableRes = fCursorDrawableRes.getInt(editText);
        Field fEditor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
        fEditor.setAccessible(true);
        Object editor = fEditor.get(editText);
        Class<?> clazz = editor.getClass();
        Field fCursorDrawable = clazz.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawable");
        fCursorDrawable.setAccessible(true);

        Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[2];
        Resources res = editText.getContext().getResources();
        drawables[0] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRes);
        drawables[1] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRes);
        drawables[0].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        drawables[1].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        fCursorDrawable.set(editor, drawables);
    } catch (final Throwable ignored) {
    }
}
```

[image: edit text with color accent]

Comment: did you try with style instead of Reflection?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use the `styles.xml` to style this. However, doing it programmatically can be done as follows:

**1. Highlight color**

First the highlight color. This can be set by using the following:

```
editText.setHighlightColor(color);
```

**2. Left and right mark**

The left and right mark are still not being colored with this. Continuing with your reflection method, we should do sort of the same for these selection markers:

```
// Left
Field fCursorDrawableLeftRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mTextSelectHandleLeftRes");
fCursorDrawableLeftRes.setAccessible(true);
int mCursorDrawableLeftRes = fCursorDrawableLeftRes.getInt(editText);

// Right
Field fCursorDrawableRightRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mTextSelectHandleRightRes");
fCursorDrawableRightRes.setAccessible(true);
int mCursorDrawableRightRes = fCursorDrawableRightRes.getInt(editText);
```

And ofcourse: adding it to the drawables list to update them (updated from your source):

```
Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[3];
Resources res = editText.getContext().getResources();
drawables[0] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRes);
drawables[1] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableLeftRes);
drawables[2] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRightRes);
drawables[0].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
drawables[1].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
drawables[2].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

**3. Result**

This means that your method will look something like:

```
private void setCursorDrawableColor(EditText editText, int color) {
    try {
        Field fCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        fCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
        int mCursorDrawableRes = fCursorDrawableRes.getInt(editText);

        // Left
        Field fCursorDrawableLeftRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mTextSelectHandleLeftRes");
        fCursorDrawableLeftRes.setAccessible(true);
        int mCursorDrawableLeftRes = fCursorDrawableLeftRes.getInt(editText);

        // Right
        Field fCursorDrawableRightRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mTextSelectHandleRightRes");
        fCursorDrawableRightRes.setAccessible(true);
        int mCursorDrawableRightRes = fCursorDrawableRightRes.getInt(editText);

        Field fEditor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
        fEditor.setAccessible(true);
        Object editor = fEditor.get(editText);
        Class<?> clazz = editor.getClass();
        Field fCursorDrawable = clazz.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawable");
        fCursorDrawable.setAccessible(true);

        Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[3];
        Resources res = editText.getContext().getResources();
        drawables[0] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRes);
        drawables[1] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableLeftRes);
        drawables[2] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRightRes);
        drawables[0].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        drawables[1].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        drawables[2].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        fCursorDrawable.set(editor, drawables);
    } catch (final Throwable ignored) {}
}
```

**// Other method (using `styles.xml`)**

As I said, I would prefer to use the styles.xml to achieve this behavior. In this case, only using the following three properties will result in the wanted behavior:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
```

(And `textColorHighlight` for highlighting of course)

Comment: Which part doesn't work for you then @mFeinstein? What isn't being colored in your case? This should work for API 21 and above at least

Comment: I am just double checking if I applied all my styles correctly... But in principle the bubble handle didn't change color. Also, I believe just `colorAccent` should be enough to change it

Comment: For the handles and bottom line, that works too yea. These values are just more specific to the control. Also, with using `colorAccent` it would still require `android:textColorHighlight` to be set for the highlighting bar on top the text. That isn't colored by the accent color.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am setting, but the EditText seems to be ignoring my style, that's why it doesn't work, I have to check it why...

Comment: Ok, I fixed, I have no idea why, but my `EditText` ignores what I set in `style` and in `textAppearance`, but it works if I pass it in `android:theme`....I have no clue why...do you?

Comment: Can be multiple things, maybe the style is being overridden by another style or the style is maybe not being set correctly. Consider creating a question on StackOverflow along with the code that you have to set the style. Your question is not in the scope of this post

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin version, works from api 14 to api 32

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
import android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable
import android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable
import android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable
import android.os.Build
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.ColorInt
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat
import androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.lang.Exception
import kotlin.math.sqrt

@SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
fun TextView.setHandlesColor(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val size = 22.spToPx(context).toInt()
        val corner = size.toFloat() / 2
        val inset = 10.spToPx(context).toInt()

        //left drawable
        val drLeft = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, intArrayOf(color, color))
        drLeft.setSize(size, size)
        drLeft.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(corner, corner, 0f, 0f, corner, corner, corner, corner)
        setTextSelectHandleLeft(InsetDrawable(drLeft, inset, 0, inset, inset))

        //right drawable
        val drRight = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, intArrayOf(color, color))
        drRight.setSize(size, size)
        drRight.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner)
        setTextSelectHandleRight(InsetDrawable(drRight, inset, 0, inset, inset))

        //middle drawable
        val drMiddle = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, intArrayOf(color, color))
        drMiddle.setSize(size, size)
        drMiddle.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner)
        val mInset = (sqrt(2f) * corner - corner).toInt()
        val insetDrawable = InsetDrawable(drMiddle, mInset, mInset, mInset, mInset)
        val rotateDrawable = RotateDrawable()
        rotateDrawable.drawable = insetDrawable
        rotateDrawable.toDegrees = 45f
        rotateDrawable.level = 10000
        setTextSelectHandle(rotateDrawable)
        return
    }

    try {
        val editorField = TextView::class.java.getFieldByName("mEditor")
        val editor = editorField?.get(this) ?: this
        val editorClass: Class<*> = if (editorField != null) {
            runCatching { Class.forName("android.widget.Editor") }.getOrNull() ?: editorField.javaClass
        } else {
            TextView::class.java
        }
        val handles = listOf(
            "mSelectHandleLeft" to "mTextSelectHandleLeftRes",
            "mSelectHandleRight" to "mTextSelectHandleRightRes",
            "mSelectHandleCenter" to "mTextSelectHandleRes"
        )
        for (i in 0 until handles.size) {
            editorClass.getFieldByName(handles[i].first)?.let { field: Field ->
                val drawable = field.get(editor) as? Drawable
                    ?: TextView::class.java.getFieldByName(handles[i].second)?.getInt(this)
                        ?.let { ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, it) }
                if (drawable != null) field.set(editor, drawable.tinted(color))
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

fun Class<*>.getFieldByName(name: String): Field? = runCatching {
    getDeclaredField(name).apply { isAccessible = true }
}.getOrNull()

fun Number.spToPx(context: Context? = null): Float =
    (context?.resources ?: Resources.getSystem()).displayMetrics
        .let { TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, this.toFloat(), it) }

fun Drawable.tinted(@ColorInt color: Int): Drawable = when {
    this is VectorDrawableCompat -> {
        this.apply { setTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color)) }
    }
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && this is VectorDrawable -> {
        this.apply { setTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color)) }
    }
    else -> {
        DrawableCompat.wrap(this)
            .also { DrawableCompat.setTint(it, color) }
            .let { DrawableCompat.unwrap(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that to also call `highlightColor = color` in order to set the color of the text that's being highlighted

Comment: this works nicely. Except on Huawei: `No field mSelectHandleLeft in class Lhuawei/com/android/internal/widget/HwEditor; (declaration of 'huawei.com.android.internal.widget.HwEditor' appears in /system/framework/hwEmui.jar)` Do you have solution there?

Comment: @Niklas i looked into TextView huawei code, and seems there is no code for handles or coloring it
https://github.com/SivanLiu/HwFrameWorkSource/blob/master/P9_8_0_0/src/main/java/android/widget/TextView.java
if you find how to fix it, can you tell later?

Comment: the only thing I've found is: https://github.com/SivanLiu/HwFrameWorkSource/blob/5b92ed0f1ccb4bafc0fdb08b6fc4d98447b754ad/P9_8_0_0/src/main/java/android/widget/Editor.java#L1974-L1980

We should be able to get access to that: https://github.com/SivanLiu/HwFrameWorkSource/blob/5b92ed0f1ccb4bafc0fdb08b6fc4d98447b754ad/P9_8_0_0/src/main/java/android/widget/Editor.java#L197

Comment: The updated version works on Huawei.

Comment: which case did you fix with your edit 20 hours ago?

Comment: @Niklas
runCatching { Class.forName("android.widget.Editor") }.getOrNull() ?: editorField.javaClass in case some vendor firmware remove this class.
Also replace handles type from ArrayMap to simple List of Pair

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for Xamarin based [on Jonh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59488928/8369297)

```
    public static void SetHandlesColor(EditText editText, Color color)
        {

            try
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q)
                {
                    var size = SpToPx(22, editText.Context);
                    var corner = size / 2f;
                    var inset = SpToPx(10, editText.Context);

                    //left drawable
                    var drLeft = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BottomTop, new[] { (int)color, color });
                    drLeft.SetSize(size, size);
                    drLeft.SetCornerRadii(new[] { corner, corner, 0f, 0f, corner, corner, corner, corner });
                    editText.TextSelectHandleLeft = new InsetDrawable(drLeft, inset, 0, inset, inset);

                    //right drawable
                    var drRight = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BottomTop, new[] { (int)color, color });
                    drRight.SetSize(size, size);
                    drRight.SetCornerRadii(new[] { 0f, 0f, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner });
                    editText.TextSelectHandleRight = new InsetDrawable(drRight, inset, 0, inset, inset);

                    //middle drawable
                    var drMiddle = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BottomTop, new[] { (int)color, color });
                    drMiddle.SetSize(size, size);
                    drMiddle.SetCornerRadii(new[] { 0f, 0f, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner, corner });
                    var mInset = (int)(System.Math.Sqrt(2f) * corner - corner);
                    var insetDrawable = new InsetDrawable(drMiddle, mInset, mInset, mInset, mInset);
                    var rotateDrawable = new RotateDrawable();
                    rotateDrawable.Drawable = insetDrawable;
                    rotateDrawable.ToDegrees = 45f;
                    rotateDrawable.SetLevel(10000);
                    editText.TextSelectHandle = rotateDrawable;
                    return;
                }

                var editorField = Class.FromType(typeof(TextView)).GetDeclaredField("mEditor");
                if (!editorField.Accessible)
                    editorField.Accessible = true;

                var editor = editorField.Get(editText);
                var editorClass = editor.Class;
                string[] handleNames = { "mSelectHandleLeft", "mSelectHandleRight", "mSelectHandleCenter" };
                string[] resNames = { "mTextSelectHandleLeftRes", "mTextSelectHandleRightRes", "mTextSelectHandleRes" };

                for (int i = 0; i < handleNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    var handleField = editorClass.GetDeclaredField(handleNames[i]);
                    if (!handleField.Accessible)
                    {
                        handleField.Accessible = true;
                    }
                    Drawable handleDrawable = (Drawable)handleField.Get(editor);

                    if (handleDrawable == null)
                    {
                        var resField = Class.FromType(typeof(TextView)).GetDeclaredField(resNames[i]);
                        if (!resField.Accessible)
                        {
                            resField.Accessible = true;

                        }
                        int resId = resField.GetInt(editText);
                        handleDrawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(editText.Context, resId);

                    }

                    if (handleDrawable != null)
                    {
                        Drawable drawable = handleDrawable.Mutate();
                        drawable.SetColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
                        handleField.Set(editor, drawable);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ReflectiveOperationException) { }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }

 public static int SpToPx(float sp, Context context)
        {
            return (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Sp, sp, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        }
```