# Change HintTextColor and Cursor Color of TextInputEditText Programmatically

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I use Spinner and TextInputEditText in my app that I would like to change some EditText features(Cursor and HintText color) when user selects spinner item. Here is my code:

```
    private void setSpinner(){
        String [] types = {"q_a", "attention", "reminder", "explain", "important", "image", "voice"};
        TypeAdapter adapter = new TypeAdapter(getActivity(), types);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        
        int [] colors = {
                R.color.actual_purple, R.color.actual_pink, R.color.actual_orange,
                R.color.actual_carrot, R.color.actual_green,
                R.color.deep_blue_grey_flat_icon, R.color.deep_blue_grey_flat_icon
        };

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                setTextEditor(colors[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setTextEditor(int color){
        Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.important_cursor);
        Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), color));
        pointEditor.setTextCursorDrawable(unwrappedDrawable);
        pointEditorLayout.setBoxBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), color));
        pointEditor.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), color));
    }
```

I don't realize why that's not working. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who work with TextInputLayout, I found the answer. Just simply use:

```
textInputLayout.setHintTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(your_color));
textInputLayout.setBoxStrokeColor(your_color);
```

And for the cursor:

```
editText.setTextCursorDrawable();
```

Answer (score 0):

For editText try

```
pointEditor.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(color));
```

For cursor color check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26543290/15119028)

Comment: Tried that, still not working. Note that I want to change the color when spinner item changes.