# Android EditText programmatically tint Typo Dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext

When you have an EditText and write an incorrect word, you get a red scribbly line. If you click on it, a MenuDialog appears where you can select either a correct translation or add it to the dictionary. It looks like this:

[image]

How can I theme this programmatically without using XML?

- At least, I'd like to change the action colors from green to a dynamic value.
- Change background color
- Change the text color
- Change the red scribbly line on the EditText